# Why is gas used depended of the given gas limit?

Tags: gas, gas-limit

I have an interesting phenomena *EDIT: on the Fantom network, sorry if this is the wrong place to ask* which I do not understand, so maybe someone is able to explain this:

When I send a transaction with e.g. 400000 gas limit to execute my contract method, X amount of gas is used.
When I send the exact same transaction with only 250000 limit, a much lower amount of gas is used.

**Example 1:**

Gas Limit: 400,000

Gas Used by Transaction: 80,726 (20.18%)

Gas Price: 0.0000002455336 FTM (245.5336 Gwei)

**Example2:**

Gas Limit: 250,000

Gas Used by Transaction: 65,726 (26.29%)

Gas Price: 0.0000002310364 FTM (231.0364 Gwei)

**Note**: The method executes **exactly** the same code in both transactions, so there is no condition different or so.

Why is that so?

EDIT:

I just tried another sequence, first with lower gas, then with higher gas limit:

**Example 3:**

Gas Limit: 350,000

Gas Used by Transaction:72,650 (20.76%)

**Example 4:**

Gas Limit: 450,000

Gas Used by Transaction: 82,650 (18.37%)

Answer (score 0):

Are you resetting the blockchain state after each transaction, or do you execute example 2 after example 1?

If the latter, that might be the reason for the lesser gas amount. For example, in a general ERC721 implementation, the mint function spends less gas the second time you call it.

Comment: Yes, 2 was executed after 1. Will try again. Not sure what you mean with resetting the blockchain state. These are transactions on the mainnet. Or do you mean if I changed the my contract storage variables? Also no. I just hand over the same input to the method. The method itself does not change the storage, does only internal caluclations, apart from one external call to getReserves() on an Uniswap pair. EDIT: Please check edit in OP

Comment: Since the blockchain state is different after every transaction, and more so if it's mainnet (which can even change outside of your transactions), you can't really compare transactions like that. You need to make sure the state is the same when comparing, otherwise you might get different result. If you're running on mainnet, one way to do it would be using hardhat to do mainnet forking - meaning, simulating the mainnet locally on your pc - you tell it to simulate the blockchain at a certain block, then run tx 1, then again simulate from the _same block before you ran your tx_, then run.....

Comment: ....tx 2. This way you'll run both of them on the same state and then the comparison will be more accurate. By the way, it's a little strange that you say they don't update storage variables. If they didn't update any contract's state, you wouldn't even need to spend gas to execute them.

Comment: And just to clarify: the gas limit shouldn't affect the amount of gas used. This is why I believe there's another factor in play here which makes you see these results.

Comment: Ok thx for the hardhat tip, but I already ran my tests on hardhat. BTW The real gas usage is way higher than I saw it on the mainnet fork via hardhat and gas reporter. Probably it has something to do that this is not Ethereum but the Fantom network. Maybe that is also the reason for my original problem....which I am 100% sure does not have to do with the changing state of the blockchain.
"you would not even spend gas to execute them" ... since when? Sorry that is not true. Everything costs gas. Multiplying two variables in memory costs gas. So I do not quite understand this comment.

Comment: what are you using to interact with your contract? and which network and chain are you using?

Comment: I am sending the transaction via web3 sendTransaction directly on my node. This is all on the Fantom network, chainId 250.

Comment: "Everything costs gas" - no. Functions that change the state cost gas. Functions that not (which are called "view"/"pure" functions) can be called in a way which will not spend gas. This is how you are able for example to see your USDC balance without spending gas. If these functions are called within a function that changes the state, then yes they will cost gas. Maybe you just don't know if it changes the state or not. For example you mentioned getReservesOut is being called. If you're doing a swap, you're changing the state.

Comment: Regarding your Hardhat comment, it is not enough to run it in hardhat, you need to fork the mainnet ( https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html ) and execute both transactions on the same state if you want to make sure the gas usage is only changing based on the gas limit. Otherwise the starting point of your experiment is simply different. Now that you say it's in Fantom, maybe there's something in Fantom that I'm not aware off. But still, until you do your experiment from the same state, then gas limit is not the only difference in the transactions.

Comment: Thanks Kenzo for your feedback. I will check and come back :)

Comment: Cheers mate :) I realized there's another thing you can check - examples 1 and 2 are the exact same tx, only different gas limit right? So you can try executing the same tx twice in a row with _same_ gas limit, and see if the gas consumption will change or not.